# How to use href as a <div> in php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

How is it possible to use the href for this full div tag?

```
<?php 

echo '<div id="" onclick="location.href="viewpost.php";" style="cursor:pointer;"> test </div>';
                echo "<div class='nieuwscol' onclick='location.href='viewpost.php';' style='cursor:pointer;'>";
                echo "<img class='imgnews' src='".$row['imgNewspost']."'>";
                          //echo '<p>'.$row['postAuteur'].'</p>';
echo '<div class="newstitle"><p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></p></div>';
 echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';
 echo '<a style="font-size: 14px;" href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'#commentsID"><img src="img/commenticon.png" alt="" height="20" width="20" ><div class="newsdate" float: right;> <p style="font-size: 14px;"> 000 </a>'.date('jS M Y', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p></div>';


              echo '</div>';
              echo '</a>';
?>
```

As you can see, the a href is working for newstitles, but now I would like to use the same weblink for the whole div. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: which div are you talking about? also you should be using href with `<a>` tag

Comment: You can watch the full live version here: http://www.elitegamegroup.nl/nieuws.php

Comment: It's the first div the the onclick javascript. class='nieuwscol'

Comment: @EGGEliteGameGroup  i will suggest you that instead of onclick. , write a jquery code that when outer div will click link click will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the url with the div like :

```
<div data-bind="<?php echo 'viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'];?>" class="div-class"></div>
```

Then write jquery function like following:

```
$(document).on("click",".div-class",function(){
        window.location = $(this).data('bind');
});
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your welcome. I'm happy to help you.Can you accept my answer please? And give an Up vote ? @EGG Elite Game Group

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `<a href="">` which contains whole div.

In your code we see `</a>` in the last `echo` which don't have start anywhere above first `echo`;